# Run script periodically that can get server hostname

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to call a middleware function in my `app.js` file periodically that takes as a parameter the current local host. By host, I do not mean `os.hostname()`, but rather the host in `http://www.host.com` or the IP address in `127.0.0.1:3000`. The only way I know of if `req.header.host` however, I am not expecting any requests to run the script and it should start running as soon as I run my application. Is there a way?

This is my code:

`app.js:`

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');

  // Script
  setInterval(function(){
    User.checkPending(server_host_goes_here);
  }, 1800000);
});
```

Comment: Have u tried page onload?

Comment: That header value is sent by the browser and can be modified in-transit. Therefore it should not be used for server-side operations that depend on the host name being accurate. One good way to accomplish this would be to make use of environment variables, and set the environment variable appropriately for each server.

Comment: @burhancerit I want to run this in the application background, even when there are no users online. So I don't thing page onload is fitting for me in this case.

Comment: @JonathanGray I think that's a nice workaround. I'll do that, thanks! :)